# AWS Lambda works once, then fails a dozen times

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda succeeds once and then fails multiple times

I have a AWS Lambda function which queries a MongoDB database (Sandbox-- db hosted in mlab) using mongoose with a phoneNumber and the database returns information about that user.

Once in a while the code executes properly, `Customer.findOne()` gets called and returns the data using `callback()`, but then multiple times in a row after this, no code inside `Customer.findOne()` gets called, and within a few milliseconds returns null.
Whenever I'm testing this code locally everything works as expected, I always get a response from the database.

Customer is a mongoose model, and mongoose is just the mongodb connection.
I had to put `mongoose.connection.close()` because without it it would timeout.

```
const { mongoose } = require('./mongoose');
const { Customer } = require('./customer');

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    var phoneNumber = '+12345678901';
    Customer.findOne({ phoneNumber }).then((c) => {
        if (!c) {
            mongoose.connection.close();
            return callback(null, { "error": "not found" });
        }
        mongoose.connection.close();
        callback(null, { "Name": c.Name });
    });
};
```

I expect the lambda function to succeed every single time, but it only succeeds once in a couple dozen times

Comment: Code looks fine. All depending on what `Customer.findOne` do. Side note, `mongoose.connection.close()` can be written above `if(!c)` since you are closing it always.

Comment: I just noticed something else, everytime I do a change and save the code (using the inline code editor) It works once, and then the second time it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Sounds like you need to set `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` and remove the `.close()`.

Comment: Yeah that fixed the issue @Michael-sqlbot